# How to compare two data rows in one data set in BIRT

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I'm new to BIRT and need an answer to the following question:
How to compare two data rows in one data set in BIRT and then print it out to the document?

Comment: can you give us some information about why/in what way you want to compare two data rows?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a reason for not using a self-join query to bring in the data.  One simple thing you could do is have 2 identical datasets and then create a new joint dataset using the 2.

Answer (score 0):

With an Oracle DB, you could easily achieve this with pure SQL using the "Analytic Function" `LAG` (see the Oracle documentation for details).

Independent from the DB, with BIRT, you could use a variable last_row:

Create some computed columns to keep the results of your comparisons. e.g. "FIRST_COLUMN_CHANGED" as boolean.

afterOpen event:

```js
last_row = null;
```

onFetch event (pls note I'm not sure wether the actual data columns start at 0 or 1):

```js
if (last_row != null) {
    if (last_row[0] == row[0]) {
        row["FIRST_COLUMN_CHANGED"] = false;
    } else {
        row["FIRST_COLUMN_CHANGED"] = true;
    }
} else {
    // do computations for the first record.
    row["FIRST_COLUMN_CHANGED"] = true;
}

// Copy the current row to last_row
last_row = {};
// modify depending on the number of columns
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    last_row[i] = row[i];
}
```